# php exec() Linux server strange output

Tags: php, linux, exec

I am attempting to backround a php script since it will take more than a minute to complete and I do not want the user to wait.

my exec command is as follows:

```
exec ('php -f path/to/file.php > path/to/output.log 2>&1 &');
```

first of all the script in the file didnt do what i programmed it to do however, the output file still recieves this output:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.24
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Link: <https://example.com/wp-json/>;
rel="https://api.w.org/"
Link: <https://example.com/?p=687>; rel=shortlink
....
```

This output is not at all what my script is supposed to make, it makes no sense to me.

the rest of the output is a html document with differnet links to my website and such.

can anyone clue me into why this is happening and not simply running the script?

BTW

I have used different commands like /usr/bin/php with the same affect

**UPDATE**

I noticed that after changing the first path/to/file.php paremeter to gibberish i.e.

```
exec ('php -f asdfjaskldfj > path/to/output.log 2>&1 &');
```

that the output remains the same, not sure what this means but i believe it to be noteworthy

Comment: once you background that shell script, `shell()` returns and your parent script continues execution. that means the parent script can quit/exit/whatever while that background job continues running, completely independently.

Comment: oops i made a mistake in my question, i meant to type exec not shell, thought of shell_exec and confused myself

Comment: Does the script have a shebang?  As a general guideline, it's often better to include one, chmod to executable, and have /bin/sh invoke it ...

Comment: doesn't matter. they're both basically the same thing, exec() just gives you the option of capturing exit values, not just output.

Comment: @ Kkinsey So i should put a command inside my backend php like /bin/sh in the beginning and just exec the file itself?

Comment: @marc B Im not sure i understand what you are telling me, isnt that what im trying to do?

Comment: oh. I see. you don't want those http headers there - php must not be  properly configured, so the cli mode thinks it's outputting into an http context. try `php -q -f` to suppress http output.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks I updated my question, to make it more clear that the output im getting is not what my script is programmed to do

Comment: @MarcB hmm... to no avail it gave the same output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After must trial and error I found that

```
usr/bin/php
```

pointed to a php command that only outputted documentation on my current server, and when I changed it to

```
usr/bin/php5
```

it worked. Very hard to find documentation on the linux php command, and I still have yet to find anyone else with the same problem, but it has been resolved nonetheless.